# How to call javascript function from .ascx file

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have script where is .JS function in .ascx file:

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
function CheckButton(){
    if($('#plcholder').length > 0){
        document.getElementById('<%= btIntoBasketAll.ClientID %>').style.display = 'inherit';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('<%= btIntoBasketAll.ClientID %>').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>
```

I want to call it from .aspx file in TabPanel's OnClientClick property:

```
<asp:TabContainer ID="tabProductList" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" OnActiveTabChanged="tabProductList_ActiveTabChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                        <asp:TabPanel ID="TabProductListCatalog" runat="server" HeaderText="<%$ Resources: Resource, TabProductListCatalog %>">
                        </asp:TabPanel>
                        <asp:TabPanel ID="TabProductListPicture" runat="server" HeaderText="<%$ Resources: Resource, TabProductListPicture %>">
                        </asp:TabPanel>
                        <asp:TabPanel ID="TabProductListList" runat="server" HeaderText="<%$ Resources: Resource, TabProductListList %>" OnClientClick="return CheckButton()">
                        </asp:TabPanel>
                    </asp:TabContainer>
```

but this doesn't work. TabPanels just dissapear in webbrowser.

Comment: Does the code in `CheckButton` even execute? Did you try placing a `console.log` there?

Comment: @DanDumitru  It won't. That is the question - how to call function in aspx which is placed in ascx.

Answer (score 0):

Try document.getElementById('<%= btIntoBasketAll.ClientID %>').style.display = 'block';

Comment: This isn't what I want. Hiding works for case when I'm reload page with F5. But when I move before Tabs (ajax), not whole page reload and therefore the button I want to hide just not hide. I think I have problem about calling function in OnClientClick.

Comment: Check source of page after rendering on browser if it contains this function CheckButton() rendered there. Ultimately .ascx becomes part of .aspx so it should work. It may be possible that this .ascx control not rendered on page

Comment: Checked and it is there.